# For some occurrences of a "theorem" environment, can we remove the parentheses -- "(" and ")" -- from the environment's optional argument?

Tags: theorems, amsthm

For some occurrences can we remove the parentheses -- `(` and `)` -- from a `theorem`'s optional argument?

I'm ready to use a command such as `\nobracket`, as shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\nobrackets
\begin{theorem}[aaa]
For this theorem don't want bracket ()
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem}[bbb]
For this theorem need bracket ()
\end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2):

You need to somehow mark when you don't want the brackets.

With your proposed syntax:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newtheoremstyle{funny}
  {}{}
  {\itshape}
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {.}
  { }
  {%
   \thmname{#1}% the label
   \thmnumber{ #2}% the number
   \thmnote{ {\mdseries\iffunny(\fi#3\iffunny)\fi}}% the note
   \global\funnytrue % restore the standard
  }
\newif\iffunny
\newcommand{\nobrackets}{\global\funnyfalse}

\theoremstyle{funny}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-6]

\nobrackets
\begin{theorem}[aaa]
For this theorem we don't want parentheses.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[2][1-6]

\begin{theorem}[bbb]
For this theorem we need parentheses.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[3][1-6]

\end{document}
```

[image]

With a better syntax:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newtheoremstyle{funny}
  {}{}
  {\itshape}
  {}
  {\bfseries}
  {.}
  { }
  {%
   \thmname{#1}% the label
   \thmnumber{ #2}% the number
   \thmnote{ {\mdseries\iffunny(\fi#3\iffunny)\fi}}% the note
  }
\newif\iffunny
\funnytrue

\theoremstyle{funny}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newenvironment{theorem*}{\funnyfalse\theorem}{\endtheorem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-6]

\begin{theorem*}[aaa]
For this theorem we don't want parentheses.
\end{theorem*}

\lipsum[2][1-6]

\begin{theorem}[bbb]
For this theorem we need parentheses.
\end{theorem}

\lipsum[3][1-6]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

On page 10 of the [user guide](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf) of the `amsthm` package, one finds instructions for how to create a theorem style that shares most properties of the default `plain` theorem style except that no parentheses are placed around the optional argument of a theorem.

The following solution builds on this material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain} % the default
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\newtheoremstyle{noparens}% cf. p. 10 of user guide of 'amsthm' package
    {}{}{\itshape}{}%
    {\bfseries}{.}{ }%
    {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{ {\mdseries #3}}}
\theoremstyle{noparens} % switch to the new theorem style
\newtheorem{theoremnp}[theorem]{Theorem} % 'theoremnp' and 'theorem' share same counter

\begin{document}

\begin{theoremnp}[aaa]
For this theorem we don't want parentheses.
\end{theoremnp}

\begin{theorem}[bbb]
For this theorem we need parentheses.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: can we get in with theorem environment. I don't want add further environment in my TeX

Comment: @Learner - According to your initial posting, you seem to be OK with a *macro* called `\nobrackets` and, presumably, a companion macro called, say, `\brackets`. However, your comment indicates that you're not OK with setting up a companion *environment* named `theoremnp`. Please help me understand your resistance.

Comment: without changing the environment can we get the required output. I can use command without changing the environments

Comment: @Learner - I believe the main issue with your request is that for the commands you appear to have in mind to "work", they would have to dynamically alter some of the properties of the existing `theorem` environment. Unfortunately, the structure of the theorem-like environments provided by the `amsthm` package is such that it's not exactly straightforward to update or "patch" the environments in a way that would let you achieve your objective. That's why I suggested create a second *environment", called `theoremnp`, and utilizing both `theorem` and `theoremnp` as needed throughout the document.